# Actionscript 3 (Kongregate ?) server-server side calls

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, post

I'm a c++ programmer who's been forced to do some tweaks to an existing AS3 game to use the kongregate api for monetization and whatnot.

I've had no big trouble with the AS3 syntax, but now in the kongregate docs it refers to "server-side" calls which use a strange http POST syntax. Something like this: http://developers.kongregate.com/docs/rest/use-item

Can anyone point me to what it's doing (not the actual effect, that's pretty well covered by the docs)? Is it using some other language? A part of AS3 that I don't know about (that doesn't look much like a high level OO language). And what does it mean server-side? How can I write server code for an app that I build into a SWF file and upload to the server?

I feel there is a big chunk of something I'm missing to be able to research what is going on, but everyone in the comments I've seen talks about "server-side" as a given, without giving me any pointers to the basics I should know to actually use it.

Thanks,
Jaime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the docs are showing you what the api is expecting (in terms of HTTP request) and it's up to you to implement it in Actionscript.

If that's the case, you could use the [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class.

Basically, you'd do something like this:

```
var url:String = "http://www.kongregate.com/api/use_item.json";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.url = url;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST
request.data = new URLVariables();
request.data.api_key = "MyApiKey";
//  etc...
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,handleComplete);
loader.load(request);

function handleComplete(e:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = e.currentTarget as URLLoader;
    trace(loader.data); //  a string containing the service response
}
```

You should also handle async errors (which I ommited in this sample). Another thing you should do is decode the JSON string into an Object to make working with the data easier. I suggest you google around for some library, there are a couple out there (off the top of my head, as3corelib, which was sponsered by adobe, had a JSON parser).

Comment: Don't forget to set `request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST`